# Possible to return multiple results with reduce function?

Tags: nosql, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-ruby

With the following schema (defined below). I can use map reduce to aggregate the delivered_count field for all days (which is an embedded array inside the campaign document).

```
  {
    campaign_id: 1,
    status: 'running',
    dates: {
      '20130926' => {
        delivered: 1,
        failed: 1,
        queued: 1,
        clicked: 1,
        males_count: 1,
        females_count: 1,
        pacific_region: { clicked_count: 10 },
        america_region: { clicked_count: 10 },
        atlantic_region: { clicked_count: 10 },
        europe_region: { clicked_count: 10 },
        africa_region: { clicked_count: 10 },
        etc_region: { clicked_count: 10 },
        asia_region: { clicked_count: 10 },
        australia_region: { clicked_count: 10 }
      },
      '20130927' => {
        delivered: 1,
        failed: 1,
        queued: 1,
        clicked: 1,
        males_count: 1,
        females_count: 1,
        pacific_region: { clicked_count: 10 },
        america_region: { clicked_count: 10 },
        atlantic_region: { clicked_count: 10 },
        europe_region: { clicked_count: 10 },
        africa_region: { clicked_count: 10 },
        etc_region: { clicked_count: 10 },
        asia_region: { clicked_count: 10 },
        australia_region: { clicked_count: 10 }
      },
      '20130928' => {
        delivered: 1,
        failed: 1,
        queued: 1,
        clicked: 1,
        males_count: 1,
        females_count: 1,
        pacific_region: { clicked_count: 10 },
        america_region: { clicked_count: 10 },
        atlantic_region: { clicked_count: 10 },
        europe_region: { clicked_count: 10 },
        africa_region: { clicked_count: 10 },
        etc_region: { clicked_count: 10 },
        asia_region: { clicked_count: 10 },
        australia_region: { clicked_count: 10 }
      }
    }
  }
```

The code below parses through field `asia_regions` outputs the value of field `clicked_count` => 30 (combined value of all data)

```
$rethinkdb.table(:daily_stat_campaigns).filter { |daily_stat_campaign| daily_stat_campaign[:campaign_id].eq 1 }[0][:dates].do { |doc|
  doc.keys.map { |key|
    doc.get_field(key)[:asia_region][:clicked_count].default(0)
  }.reduce { |left, right|
    left+right
  }
}.run
```

Is it possible to run the code above but against multiple regions? This way I can run one query which will return multiple sums. The output i'm trying to achieve is something similar to the pseudo result below.

```
[{ asia_region: {clicked_count: 30}}, {america_region: {clicked_count: 30} }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
require 'awesome_print' # For better readability on output

regions = [:pacific_region, :america_region]
reg_clicks = $rethinkdb.table(:daily_stat_campaigns).filter { |daily_stat_campaign| daily_stat_campaign[:campaign_id].eq 1 }[0][:dates].do { |doc|
  doc.keys.concat_map { |key|
    doc
    .get_field(key)
    .pluck(regions)
    .coerce_to("ARRAY")
  }
}
ap reg_clicks.run
```

Will output something like: `[["america_region", {"clicked_count"=>10}], ["pacific_region", {"clicked_count"=>10}], ["america_region", {"clicked_count"=>10}], ["pacific_region", {"clicked_count"=>10}], ["america_region", {"clicked_count"=>10}], ["pacific_region", {"clicked_count"=>10}]]`

```
aggregate = reg_clicks.map { |reg|
  { reg: reg[0], clicked_count: reg[1][:clicked_count] }
}
ap aggregate.run
```

Will output: `[{"reg"=>"america_region", "clicked_count"=>10}, {"reg"=>"pacific_region", "clicked_count"=>10}, {"reg"=>"america_region", "clicked_count"=>10}, {"reg"=>"pacific_region", "clicked_count"=>10}, {"reg"=>"america_region", "clicked_count"=>10}, {"reg"=>"pacific_region", "clicked_count"=>10}]`

```
ap aggregate.group_by(:reg, $rethinkdb_rql.sum(:clicked_count)).run
```

Outputs: `[{"reduction"=>30, "group"=>{"reg"=>"america_region"}}, {"reduction"=>30, "group"=>{"reg"=>"pacific_region"}}]`

Comment: Wondering if above can be done much simpler with `grouped_mapped_reduce`

Comment: Just what i was looking for. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused about the code that you posted. Why is everything inside of a `filter`? To output something like what you want do the following:

```
regions = [:pacific_region, :america_region, ...]
reg_clicks = r.table(:daily_stat_campaigns).concat_map { |row|
                 row[:dates]
                 .coerce_to("ARRAY")
                 .map{ |date| date[0] }
                 .pluck(regions)
                 .coerce_to("ARRAY")
              }
```

You can now run reg_clicks and it should look something like this:

```
$ reg_clicks.run()
[[:asia_region, {clicked_count: 30}], [:etc_region, {clicked_count: 30}], ...]
```

Now we need to do one last transformation to aggregate it:

```
$ aggregate = reg_clicks.map{ |reg|
                  {reg: reg[0], clicked_count: reg[0][:clicked_count]}
              }
              .group_by(:reg, r.sum(:clicked_count))
```

this will give you output that looks like:

```
[{group: :asia_region, reduction: 150} ...]
```

if you want it too look exactly like what you want then you can apply a final transformation:

```
aggregate.map{ |row|
    [row[:group], row[:reduction]]
}
.coerce_to("OBJECT")
```

---

These queries would definitely be a bit nicer if you normalized the data a bit. Breaking things out into a 2 more tables called :dates and :region_clicks that looked like so:

```
#dates
{
    id: 0
    campaign_id: 1
    date: '20130927'
    delivered: 1,
    failed: 1,
    queued: 1,
    clicked: 1,
    males_count: 1
}

#region_clicks
{
    region: "asia_region",
    click_count: 30,
    date_id: 0
}
```

Then your query would be as simple as:

```
r.table(:region_clicks).group_by(:region, r.sum(:click_count)).run()
```

Comment: Hi Joe, I believe Marc is using `filter` so that he can aggregate the days of only one campaign. Second, he is wanting to embed, rather than reference. Unless you think the embedded array of dates might be too large and cause some kind of a performance impact. The intention here is only to store no more than 90 days per campaign. What are your thoughts?

Comment: Joe, the code you suggested. Returns the following error: `RethinkDB::RqlRuntimeError: Cannot perform pluck on a non-object non-sequence "20130926".`